# Laravel get inside of a get

Tags: laravel, get, nested

Im totally new to Laravel and I have a question about the way you are supposed to retrieve models inside of models in Laravel. For example model A contains n-number of model B contains an n-number of model C. aka. model A hasMany model B hasMany model C.

Now I need to display a graph in HTML which includes data from models A/B/C.

Sample code

```
A::all()->each( function($A)
{
    foreach($A->B()->get() as $B) 
    {
        foreach($B->C()->orderBy("id", "desc")->get() as $C)
        {
            foreach($C['attributes'] as $attribute)
            {
                //Do stuff with attributes
            }
        } 
    }
});
```

content of A(), B(), C()

```
public function A()
{
    return $this->hasMany('A');
}
```

You see the nested foreach loops, which each makes a query. Not good at all. You could get all of this in 1 SQL statement. My question will be two-fold.

1) Does each get() method run a query against the database, or are they pren upon the generation of the class? Does Laravel automatically cache query results?

2) Am I even looking in the right direction, or is my code totally wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First, instead of using `get()` you can just use the relationship function like it was a property:

```
foreach($A->B as $B)
```

Now you are right with your assumption, currently every `get()` causes a query. The way to fix that is [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading). Meaning you load the relationship once for all models and afterwards you just access them in-memory.

This is how eager loading one relationship works:

```
A::with('B')->get();
```

Since you have *nested relations* you can use the "dot" syntax to eager load all of them right away:

```
A::with('B.C')->get();
```

And your complete code would look like this:

```
A::with('B.C')->get()->each(function($A){
    foreach($A->B as $B){
        foreach($B->C as $C){
            foreach($C['attributes'] as $attribute)
            {
                //Do stuff with attributes
            }
        } 
    }
});
```

And don't forget to add the `orderBy` to your relation:

```
public function C(){
    return $this->hasMany('C')->orderBy('id', 'desc');
}
```

(You could also do the order by when eager loading by passing a closure in `with()` but I recommend you do it in the relationship directly)

Comment: This hits the spot, perfect answer!